# makefile C code compile and link in one step but want two separate steps

Tags: gcc, makefile

My currently working makefile uses gcc to compile and link in one step. It is 600 lines long so I have cut it down to just show you the 'compile and link' and hex stages (very cut down code here!)

```
$(PROGRAM_ELF): \
    $(BSP_DIR)/install/lib/$(CONFIGURATION)/libmetal.a \
    $(BSP_DIR)/install/lib/$(CONFIGURATION)/libmetal-gloss.a \
    $(BSP_DIR)/metal.$(LINK_TARGET).lds
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(MAKE) -C $(SRC_DIR) $(basename $(notdir $@)) \
     PORT_DIR=$(PORT_DIR) \
     AR=$(RISCV_AR) \
     CC=$(RISCV_GCC) \
     CXX=$(RISCV_GXX) \
     ASFLAGS="$(RISCV_ASFLAGS)" \
     CCASFLAGS="$(RISCV_CCASFLAGS)" \
     CFLAGS="$(RISCV_CFLAGS)" \
     CXXFLAGS="$(RISCV_CXXFLAGS)" \
     XCFLAGS="$(RISCV_XCFLAGS)" \
     LDFLAGS="$(RISCV_LDFLAGS)" \
     LDLIBS="$(RISCV_LDLIBS)" \
     PROJ_SRC="$(PROJ_SRC)"

$(PROGRAM_HEX): \
    $(PROGRAM_ELF)
    $(RISCV_OBJCOPY) -O ihex $(PROGRAM_ELF) $@
    mv $(PROGRAM_HEX) $(PROGRAM_TMP)
    $(RISCV_OBJCOPY) -O verilog $(PROGRAM_ELF) $@
    cp $(PROGRAM_HEX) $(PROGRAM_MEM)
    mv $(PROGRAM_TMP) $(PROGRAM_HEX)
```

However, I need the 'compile and link stage' to be in 2 steps now as I'll be using a different compiler which has separate compile and link exes. How would I do this ? So the above would need to be split into 2. Examples online are a bit vague.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is a bit vague as well :).  In fact, this makefile doesn't compile anything or link anything.  It just runs some other make process (in the `$(SRC_DIR)` dirctory).  We have no idea, from this question, what _that_ makefile does.

Comment: it's 600 lines long so I had to cut it down a *lot*. The part I show above is where we compile and link the SRC files

Comment: I don't think you understood what I was saying.  There is NO compile command and NO link command anywhere in the makefile rules you've provided.  What this rule does is run a new instance of `make` in the `$(SRC_DIR)` subdirectory: `$(MAKE) -C $(SRC_DIR) ...`.  That's all it does.  No doubt that that new instance of make, guided by the makefile in the `$(SRC_DIR)` subdirectory (which you haven't shown any of) does the compile command and the link command.  But we can't suggest how you might want to change these makefiles without seeing those rules to know what they do and how.

Answer (score 0):

at its simplest, you use the gcc (or g++) `-c` option to compile the source without linking. This will generate an object file - which you can use in the linker state. Here is a simple example:

```
SOURCE = test.cpp
OBJECT = test.o
OUTPUT = run

all:
    @g++ $(SOURCE) -c -o $(OBJECT)     <------ Compile test.cpp, produces test.o
    @g++ $(OBJECT) -o $(OUTPUT)        <------ Links test.o into executable `run`

clean: 
    @$(RM) -rf $(OBJECT) $(OUTPUT)
```

That's it...

Answer (score 0):

I did this which seemed to work:

```
#list of all files
PROJ_SRC =  $(SRC_DIR)/plsi2c_riscv.c \
        $(SRC_DIR)/SimSpi.c \
        etc

#assume BUILD_FOLDER defined already
OBJ_FILES = $(addprefix $(BUILD_FOLDER)/,$(PROJ_SRC:.c=.o))

$(BUILD_FOLDER)/%.o: %.c
    #Create the folder structure for the output file
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(MY_CC) $(CCFLAGS) $< -o $@


$(BUILD_FOLDER)/example: $(OBJ_FILES)
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @echo Linking $(notdir $@)
    $(MY_LINK) $(LFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```